# How do I cut and paste raw bytes in emacs?

Tags: copy-paste

Here are some raw bytes shown in emacs that are printing correctly:

[image]

I can see that those are the actual bytes with `od -bc` on the command line:

[image]

When I use control-space to mark, control-w to cut, and control-y to yank, it drops something different:

[image]

`od -bc` confirms it is different:

[image]

How do I faithfully cut and paste the first thing, which has the raw bytes I want?

I'm using Emacs 22.1.1 on OS X.

(This is a place name, [Łódź](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_%C5%81%C3%B3d%C5%BA).)

**EDIT**: I did not find how to edit raw bytes in general.  However, for my bytes, it was sufficient to edit the file in the "cp1250" encoding.  I did this with:

```
C-x C-m c cp1250-unix RET C-x C-f <filename>
```

described [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingEncodings).  (The "unix" part means to leave line endings alone.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-file-literally` to:

> Visit file FILENAME with no conversion of any kind.
> Format conversion and character code conversion are both disabled,
> and multibyte characters are disabled in the resulting buffer.

For more details (including information about "format conversion" and
"character code conversion"), see the description of this command in
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Visiting Functions`.